# How to update state after deletion with Reducer in React?

Tags: reactjs, reduce

How should I update the state after a comment is deleted from the db.

This is my delete function but I cannot seem to figure out what have to be the contents of dispatch:

```
const onCommentDelete = async (id) => {
    const commentId = id;
    const response = await commentService.deleteComment(commentId);
    dispatch({
        type: 'COMMENT_DELETE',
        payload: commentId,
    });
}
```

I am also not sure how to remove this specific comment from the state in the actual Reducer? I am trying something like this, but still cannot get it to work:

```js
switch (action.type) {
    case 'COMMENT_DELETE':
        return {
            ...state,
                comments: state.comments.filter((comment, commentId) 
                => commentId !== action.payload)
        } 
    //...
}
```

The comments in the DB look like this:

```js
[
    {
        "_ownerId": "35c62d76-8152-4626-8712-eeb96381bea8",
        "blogId": "0977d18f-fa62-473b-9ee0-16a5d8910d14",
        "comment": "First comment",
        "_createdOn": 1680544822712,
        "_id": "2ce82346-19b9-471c-9ae2-f6efd0b2891c"
    },
    //...
]
```

I did read some previous threads but cannot understand how to use the information from them...

Comment: what is the structure of your state? maybe you can just pass the deleted comment's id when dispatching and remove the matching comment from the state?

Comment: If I understand your question it is an array of objects. So the commentId is the id of a single comment. 
And if I understand your suggestion I should pass the commentId like this:

        dispatch({
            type: 'COMMENT_DELETE',
            payload: commentId,
        })

But then when I try to filter this particular comment from the state I cannot seem to write it correctly....

Comment: No problem, you can update the question by adding the code you used for filtering the comments and also add the structure of your state managed by that reducer.

Comment: Presumably your redux state has the comment IDs. So pass that to the reducer, then remove the comment with said ID. If it's in an array, something like `return { ...state, comments: state.comments.filter(comment => comment.id !== action.commentID) }`.

Comment: @lemouserat when using filter the second param would be the index of each item in the array so you need to compare `action.payload` with something inside `comment` like `action.payload !== comment._id`.

Comment: @super Thank you for your suggestion. It did update the state but removes all comments from the page this way...

Comment: @RameshReddy Thank you for your additional questions and suggestions. 
It did work out like this:
comments: state.comments.filter(comment => comment._id !== action.payload)

I am still learning and it is hard for me to apply suggestions from other threads to my code.

Thank you a lot. I will now try to use this knowledge in other use cases.

Comment: Have a look I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. update your endpoint and make it return the new comments list so you can pass it as `action.payload` to `state.comments` directly.
2. you make another API call to get all the comment after you delete one of them. (**not recommanded**)
3. update your state based on the returned id as you are trying to do:

```js
return {
  ...state,
    comments: state.comments.filter((comment) 
    => comment.id !== action.payload)
}
```

The filter method takes two parameters, the first is the element the second is the index, so your code does not work or let's say returns an empty array because the function cannot find in any of the itterations an index equal to `action.payload` you have to filter based on the `comment.id` instead.
Learn more about [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The difference between the first and the third method is that the first will ensure that your state and your database are always synchronized, however in the third you try to make them synchronized manually, this can be a good solution if the data is really large otherwise it is better to opt for the first approach.

Comment: This is more of a suggestion than an answer. And it's not a good idea to update the API to return all comments as the app could have thousands of comments.

Answer (score 0):

A simple step you can do is do a refetch every time you dispatch this action.

you can achieve this by making like a boolean flag (maybe) called isSuccess and this boolean flag will be watched by the deps array in useEffect and whenever it's changing the refetch callback will be called.

tip: make sure that you only fire the callback when it's true